# Excel 2010 - load a text file "as text"

Tags: excel, csv, formatting, excel-2010

Is there anyway I can get Excel 2010 to load a text file as pure text, i.e. apply no interpretation to any field? I need to modify a large CSV file with several hundred columns (basically remove some columns). It's health data, so some of the columns are:

- NHS number "123456789012", which Excel displays as 1.23E09
- Hospital ID: "0123456", which Excel displays as "123456". The leading zero is important here.
- Various 2 char status codes where the leading zero is imports, i.e. "01" does not mean "1".

I don't want to have to go through all 297 columns reformatting them correctly. Please help!

Comment: Have you considered to write a simple Python script to remove the columns? Otherwise, this seems to be a topic that might be more relevant at http://superuser.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From main menu `Data` select `From Text` (or similar. I don't know if it is the correct label in English Excel version. On my version it is the third button from left on the `Data` ribbon).

Then choose your csv file. You will get a wizard where you have to choose the column separator character and especially the import format of the columns. Here you should select all columns and then choose the radio button 'Text'. This should import all data as plain text.